# Please Fix the PostgreSQL Icon

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, advertising

The tiny icon ([this one http://sstatic.net/so/img/tag-postgresql.png](http://sstatic.net/so/img/tag-postgresql.png)) on the [PostgreSQL tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) is nasty. Could we change it to use the favicon from [their website](https://www.postgresql.org/) ([image: to this one])?

Comment: No longer relevant: the PostGreSQL tag doesn't have an icon on it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they sent us the icon, so it's their choice. I agree it doesn't read well at 16x16, but it's what they gave us.

Comment: This speaks of an attitude that says "any sponsor who wants to can attach some arbitrary logo to any tag, for the right price". How is that "responsible advertising"?

Comment: @bignose it's a fine logo, it's just not a good choice for 16x16, as you can't really tell what it is.

Comment: Maybe you could make it bigger that way they could get more value for their investment? Like 64x64. They get something we can make sense of, and we lose something we can't make sense of... Win-win.

Answer (score 5):

If you notice, when you go to the tag page you [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql), at the top of the page it explains why the icon is as it is.

The icons for the tags do not necessarily represent the product the tag is describing.  The icons represent a company that is paying to have their logo next to that tag.  In this case [Command Prompt Inc.](http://www.commandprompt.com/) is sponsoring the `postgresql` tag, which is why the tag carries the Command Prompt logo, not the Postgres logo.

Sponsored tags have been [discussed extensively](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sponsored-tags) here on meta.

Answer (score 3):

The tag is sponsored, and it is up to the advertiser to choose the image.  Note that they are NOT advertising PostgreSQL the project, and therefore may be unable to use the project's trademarked icon, or even one very similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for putting that link... I hadn't realized what the logo was supposed to be.  Good thing it's not being sponsored by a graphics design firm!

ObPlug:  The Command Prompt guys have helped me out a couple of times and are pretty awesome to work with.